# Grant access to Windows Registry key using VBS or BAT

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I cannot find a way to grant access to **Windows Registry key** using `VBS` or `BAT`.

This link doesnot help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728310(v=ws.10).aspx

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I found great answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854772/how-can-i-use-vbscript-to-add-or-change-permissions-on-a-registry-key

To use a script to change permissions defined in a registry key from a command prompt:

Install the latest version of the Windows NT Server 4.0 Resource Kit.
Create a script file that contains the change commands:
Start any text editor (such as Notepad).
Type the registry keys and the appropriate permissions in the following format
\Registry\hive\key [permissions]
where hive is the name of the registry hive, key is the name of the registry key, and [permissions] is the binary number format of the permissions.

For example, to modify the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software** registry key to give the Administrators group and the Creator/Owner group Full Control permission and the Everyone group Read permission, type the following string:
**\Registry\Machine\Software [1 5 8]**
NOTE: You must type the permissions in the binary number format. You must also refer to the registry hive in the predefined format. For more information about how to refer to a registry hive in a script file and about the binary numbers for various types of permissions, refer to the 'Reference to Registry Hives and Binary Number Representation for Permissions' section in this article.
Save and then close the script file.
Type the following command at a command prompt, and then press ENTER
**REGINI [-m \computername]** scriptname
where computername is the name of the computer and scriptname is the name of the script file you just created.

NOTE: Use the **-m** option only when you edit the registry of a remote computer. Be sure to include the entire path to the script file.
Reference to Registry Hives and Binary Number Representation for Permissions

Refer to registry hives as indicated below:

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - \Registry\Machine
  HKEY_USERS - \Registry\Users
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER - \Registry\User\User_SID (where User_SID is the current
```

user's security identifier)

Permissions and their binary number representations are as follows:

```
Administrator Full 1
Administrator R 2
Administrator RW 3
Administrator RWD 4
Creator Full 5
Creator RW 6
World Full 7
World R 8
World RW 9
World RWD 10
Power Users Full 11
Power Users RW 12
Power Users RWD 13
System Op Full 14
System Op RW 15
System Op RWD 16
System Full 17
System RW 18
System R 19
Administrator RWX 20
```

You can use the Regdmp utility, also included with the Resource Kit, to obtain the current permissions of a registry key in the binary number format.